# Reactjs show/hide one of two divs within larger set

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to toggle between one of two divs among a larger set in a Reactjs project. There are four total pairs of divs, each pair consists of a 'name' div and a 'summary' div. The goal is to switch from the name (default visible) to the summary (default hidden) on click, and switch back if clicked again.

The below code seemed to accomplish, but all of them change if one is clicked (only one at a time should). I think this is because of a shared state, but I can't figure out how to capture and process which was clicked so it can change only that corresponding div. I put two of the four pairs into the snippet for the sake of room.

Thanks!

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      shown: true,
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      shown: !this.state.shown
    });
  }

  render() {
    var shown = {
      display: this.state.shown ? "block" : "none"
    };
    var hidden = {
      display: this.state.shown ? "none" : "block"
    }

return (
<div className="App">
      
  <div className="row">

    <div className="mod-sum-container-s ml-auto" style={ shown } onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>NAME 1...</div>

    <div className="mod-sum-container-s mod-sum-active ml-    auto" style={ hidden } onClick= {this.toggle.bind(this)}>SUMMARY 1...</div>

  </div>

  <div className="row">

    <div className="mod-sum-container-s ml-auto" style={ shown } onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>NAME 2...</div>

    <div className="mod-sum-container-s mod-sum-active ml-    auto" style={ hidden } onClick= {this.toggle.bind(this)}>SUMMARY 2...</div>

  </div>
)
```

Comment: do you need to toggle when user clicks name 1 to summary 1,, and again summary 1 to name1 ?

Comment: Yep that's correct - on click it would change to summary, then back to name if the user clicks again. But it would not impact the other name/summary pairs. Thanks.

Comment: let me know is this you need https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sx3iis ?

Comment: Thanks much - I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This worked exactly as needed - thank you very much.

Comment: I upvoted, but don't have the reputation to make it visible - thanks.

Comment: No problem.glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining two states and a single function is enough for this case, all you need to do is:

```
this.state = {
  NAME1: true,
  NAME2: true,
};
```

and in JSX, set the data-* attrib like `data-name="NAME1"`

```
    <div className="row">

        <div className="mod-sum-container-s ml-auto" style={{display : this.state.NAME1 ? "block" : "none" }} onClick={this.toggle} data-name="NAME1">NAME 1...</div>

        <div className="mod-sum-container-s mod-sum-active ml-    auto" style={{display : !this.state.NAME1 ? "block" : "none" }}  onClick= {this.toggle}  data-name="NAME1">SUMMARY 1...</div>

  </div>

  <div className="row">

        <div className="mod-sum-container-s ml-auto" **style={{display : this.state.NAME2 ? "block" : "none" }}** onClick={this.toggle} **data-name="NAME2"**>NAME 2...</div>

        <div className="mod-sum-container-s mod-sum-active ml-    auto" style={{display : !this.state.NAME2 ? "block" : "none" }} data-name="NAME2" onClick= {this.toggle}>SUMMARY 2...</div>

  </div>
```

and in `this.toggle`

```
   toggle =(e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.name]: !this.state[e.target.dataset.name]
    }, () => console.log(this.state));
  }
```

You can check the full demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sx3iis)

Answer (score 0):

you can use expression and set the state on toggle

```js
    


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name: true,
          summary: false
        };
      }

      toggle() {
        this.setState({
          name: !this.state.name,
          summary: !this.state.summary,
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <div className = "App" >
         <div className = "row" >
          {this.state.name &&
            <div className = "mod-sum-container-s ml-auto"
               onClick = {this.toggle.bind(this)} > Name </div>}
        {this.state.summary && <div className = "mod-sum-container-s mod-sum-active ml-auto"  onClick = {this.toggle.bind(this)}> Summary</div>}
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```